# How do we restrict the dev users from uploading to chef server using web UI

Tags: chef-infra

How do we restrict the dev users to upload the cookbooks, roles and environments from local machine using knife or berks install or upload, do we have different ways to restrict the user using web UI chef server? please avdice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Same as via the API, using the ACL system. You can manage ACLs either via the Manage web UI or via the (very very footgun-tastic) knife-acl gem.